# How to insert numbers from 1 to 1000 to a table what i created in a procedure?

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE number()
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE number(numberINT);
    DECLARE numb INT DEFAULT 100000;
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
    WHILE i<numb DO
        INSERT INTO number(number) VALUES(i);
        SET i=i+1;
    END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But i keep getting an error at line '4 at DO, but i dont know why.

The error message:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE szam INT DEFAULT 100000;
>       DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
>       WHILE i

Comment: I think DECLARE needs to come first in a procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare.html), you can only use `DECLARE` at given locations:

> `DECLARE` is permitted **only inside a `BEGIN` ... `END` compound
>   statement and must be at its start**, before any other statements.
>
> Declarations must follow a certain order. Cursor declarations must
>   appear before handler declarations. Variable and condition
>   declarations must appear before cursor or handler declarations.

<sub>(You're also missing a space at `numberINT`.)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

DECLARE statements should come at first. The below procedure code works.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE number()
BEGIN
    DECLARE numb INT DEFAULT 100000;
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
    CREATE TABLE number(number INT);
    WHILE i<numb DO
    INSERT INTO number(number) VALUES(i);
    SET i=i+1;
END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```